# what state/s does flink create when using the tableApi to join multiple tables?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-table-api

I have multiple streams that I want to join (A to B, B to C , C to D...) to create one Z
when using the table api and joining 3 tables
`select * from A inner join B  on a.pk_id = b.fk_id  inner join C  on b.pk_id = c.fk_id`

 what is/are the underlying state/s looks like?

 the keys are different from each source, if it is running in parallel. does Flink reshuffle the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can figure this out by looking at the job graph in the web UI. There's a shuffle being done everywhere you see a HASH connection.

This information is also included in the output of `EXPLAIN <query>`, but that's harder to grok (look for `Exchange`).

Comment: I see, thanks. what about the state? what data type is being store? how can I see its' size?

Comment: The SQL engine tries to keep as little state as possible. The state isn't readily visible or inspectable. You can get some idea of its size by looking at a savepoint.